# Remove the background of an image in Css

Tags: html, css, image

I have a logo, which is not of rectangular or square shaped. I have removed the background of the image. But when i try to write a class in css, it shows the background as white, since the class itself comes as squared or rectangular.

```css
.logo1{
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Santipur_B.Ed_College_Logo.png');
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo1"> </div>
```

Right now the background is white, so it feels correct. But when the background color is something else, a square white box is shown around the image. I want to remove that square white box around the logo.

Comment: `background-color: transparent`

Comment: Well if your image doesnt have transparency you cant do this...

Comment: The colour of the page is white, so that's what you see. Try giving the `body` a background color.

Comment: @Kiwad What makes you think there's no transparency in the image?

Comment: The image is transparent. Still i was unable to do it.
Anyways now it is working.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping.

Comment: The image had some problem. I was setting it to jpg, instead of png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is looking good here. Make sure the image is in `png` format where you are using it and has background transparent.

```css
body {background: #ff0;}
.logo1{
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Santipur_B.Ed_College_Logo.png');
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo1"> </div>
```

Comment: Welcome Vikram! Glad, it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for :

```
.logo1 {  
   mix-blend-mode:multiply;

  }
```

Or

```
.logo1 {  
    mix-blend-mode:darken;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Background transparent is what you're looking for.

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}

.logo1 {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Santipur_B.Ed_College_Logo.png') no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo1"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background color:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

OR

```
background-color: transparent;
```

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

```css
. logo1{
        filter: invert (100%).
    }
```

if logo/image is black then it will turn into white and white will turn into black.
it works 100%